# Generating normal distribution by random generation of each binary bit

Tags: statistics, random-variables, normal-distribution, random, binary

I'm making a circuit that draws a random amount of current by switching parallel resistors on or off. The resistances increase by factors of two from resistor to resistor, so this can be modeled as generating a word by randomly setting each bit. With a 50/50 chance of each one being on or off, the generated words follows a uniform distribution.

I want the current to be normally distributed. I can set the probability of each resistor being on or off arbitrarily. Is there any way to use this capability to get a normal distribution?

I'm leaning towards there not being one, or else there would be no need for the Box-Muller transform. But if I'm wrong, this method would be a big help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the circuit set-up--in particular how many 0/1 
random variables you can generate, or whether you are talking about a
discrete or continuous uniform distribution. Also, I don't know what
operations you can perform on the uniform random variables. So I can only make generic
suggestions--I hope $\ge 1$ useful ones.

(1) By summing a large number of $X_i \sim \mathsf{Bernouli}(p=.5)$
random variables (derived from _discrete uniform) you can get a binomial random variable that may be
indistinguishable from normal.

In the R simulation below I generate 100 Bernoullis and normalize to get a RV $Z$ that is perpaps
close enough to $\mathsf{Norm}(0,1).$ This procedure is replicated to get 1000 $Z$'s.
They are close enough to normal to look 'good' (essentially linear) in a normal probability
plot, but not good enough to fool a Shapiro-Wilk test for normality (not shown).

```
> set.seed(306)
> z = replicate(1000, (sum(rbinom(100, 1, .5))-50)/5)
> mean(z); sd(z); qqnorm(z, pch=20)
[1] -2e-04    # aprx 0
[1] 1.055706  # aprx 1
```

[image]

(2) If you have *continuous* standard uniforms, summing 12 of them and subtracting 
the number 6, will get you *very* close to standard normal. (This was
the method of generating normal variates used in the early days of computing when only the four basic
arithmetic operations were 'cheap'.)

```
> set.seed(318)
> z = replicate(1000, sum(runif(12))-6)
> mean(z); sd(z); shapiro.test(z) 
[1] -0.02129932
[1] 0.9895096

        Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  z 
W = 0.9984, p-value = 0.5104
```

(3) If you can generate continuous standard uniform random variables,
you can get standard exponential ones, and then use Box-Muller.

(4) If you can generate continuous standard uniform random variables,
you can use Wichura's rational function approximation to the inverse
standard normal CDF $\Phi^{-1}(U) \sim \mathsf{Norm}(0,1).$

My suggestion (4) is
now the method used in R statistical software to get standard normal
random variables: `runif` is a source of continuous standard uniforms;
`qnorm` is the inverse standard normal CDF ('quantile function'); and
`rnorm` generates standard normals using the method just described.
(Legacy and efficiency issues limit *this exact demo* to one random variable at a time,
but the method is sound.)

```
> set.seed(1234); rnorm(1)
[1] -1.207066
> set.seed(1234); qnorm(runif(1))
[1] -1.207066
```

Comment: I wound up going with a simpler method. I realized I didn't need to set each bit individually, and could instead generate the word directly. So I generated a uniform continuous random variable on [0,1) easily enough and used that with hard-coded thresholds based on the CDF of a truncated normal distribution.

However, there's some very useful information in this post, so I marked it as the answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with random bits using an algorithm presented by C.F.F. Karney, "[Sampling exactly from a normal distribution](http://arxiv.org/abs/1303.6257v2)".

This algorithm involves building up uniform random numbers one bit at a time, from left to right, using unbiased random bits, and doing comparisons with these numbers. If these comparisons succeed, this means the initial bits of a normal random number have thus been generated, so the algorithm can fill up additional digits to the right with unbiased random bits. For details on the algorithm, see the paper.

In case the "Bernoulli trial generator" outputs *biased* random bits, the algorithm can produce *unbiased* random bits from those biased bits using a *randomness extraction* technique, such as von Neumann's algorithm, Peres's iterated von Neumann method, or Zhou and Bruck's "extractor tree" (see my [note on randomness extraction](https://peteroupc.github.io/randextract.html)).